# Install4j: can I run linux service with different user?

Tags: service, install4j

I have an Install4j installer that installs a service on linux. I used a Launcher and "install as service" action. I found that it needs to be run as root. Is there anyway I can run it under different user? I saw there are options in the "install as service" for windows to choose different user account to run with. But I didn't see any for options for linux.